# Culture info usage while converting string to float type

Tags: type-conversion, converters, cultureinfo, decimalformat

I am trying to convert the input that I got from the user(string)to float and for float number format(15.6,4.5...)

`string checkedNumber = txtResult.Text.Replace(',', '.'); number1 = Convert.ToSingle(checkedNumber);`
I already tried that but it didnt help
So I updated now
`string checkedNumber = txtResult.Text.Replace(',', '.'); number1 = Convert.ToSingle(checkedNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`
to this and now its working but;
My first question is if I am converting a type to float type shouldnt ToSingle() method be able to converting float type numbers(15.6) correctly.Example calculation when I dont use InvariantCulture: 5.4 + 1 = 55
And my second question is I couldnt really understand the functioning of Invariant Culture?And last one is how could I fix this problem if I didnt use InvariantCulture. Thank you in advance for your answers.